# Django form class widget with drop down populated from database

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Django 3.2 and I am trying to create a form class that has a field (category) populated from a database model.

This is a snippet of my form class:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...
   
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'teaser', 'category', 'guest_author','content', 'tags', 'is_published']
        categories = [] #forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ArticleCategory.objects.all().order_by('name'))

        widgets = {
            'guest_author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
            'teaser': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices=categories, attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
            'tags': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
            'is_published': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-input'})
        }
```

I found out if I created the field as an instance attrribute like this:

> category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ArticleCategory.objects.all().order_by('name'))

Then I am able to use the form (with no errors raised). But I want to be able to specify the widget to use for that field, using the above declaration - is there anyway to do this - or am I restricted to simply declaring the field as an instance variable of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Form fields can take an optional `widget` argument when you define them, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ArticleCategory.objects.all().order_by('name'),
                       widget= the widget you want to use)
```

Comment: The widget I am using is declared as follows: `forms.Select(choices=categories, attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),`  What do I pass as the first argument (instead of `choices`) to `form.Select()` ?

Comment: Seems (from the docs that the default widget is `Select`, it also looks like I don't need to specify `choices`. I'll give it a try and if it works, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Yes the default widget for a `ModelChoiceField` is a `Select` widget.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Did this work for you?